# Comparing Object properties

Tags: swift, reflection, rawrepresentable

I'm trying to compare two objects to check which properties were updated. I'm using Mirror to list the properties and try the comparison. Code is:

```
let mirrorLote = Mirror(reflecting: l)
let mirrorLoteUpd = Mirror(reflecting: lUpd)

mirrorLote.children.forEach { child in
    if (child.label != "id") {
        mirrorLoteUpd.children.forEach { childUpd in
            if (child.label == childUpd.label && child.value != childUpd.value){
                addUpdatesDB(prop: child.label, val: childUpd.value)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Type 'Any' cannot conform to 'RawRepresentable'

when trying to compare the values (`child.value != childUpd.value`).

Any ideas on how can I resolve this?